# What happened to Bnei Yakov?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shevatim-12-tribes, yosef

From the time of the sale of Yosef (Chapter 37) until the decision to head to Egypt (Chapter 42) we don't hear about the story/goings on of brothers (excluding Yehudah). We have flash references for a divide that the Yosef incident caused (Sotah 13B) but nothing substantial about the lives of the brother's.

Is anyone aware of sources in the Gemoro, Medrash or Meforshim that provide glimpses or more info about their lives in this time?

Comment: The Midrash tells a wonderful story about Asher's daughter Sarach musically preparing Yaakov Aveinu for the news Yosef was alive, so at the very least we can derive from that that Asher married and had a daughter :)

Comment: @JoshK The verse tells us he had a daughter.

Comment: I have that question about Yitzchok Avinu. Why is there so little reference to him in the Torah? Other than the Torah's references to his travels  what else did he do before Yaakov and Esav were born? What did he do after Yaakov went to Lavan? He lived many years after that.